# API calls for SwiftUI application

Tags: ios, swift, api, swiftui

I'm trying to make an easy application in SwiftUI for iOS. I'm following the instructions of a YouTube video which shows how to make an API call from PokeAPI in order to show a List of Pokemon in the view. I made every single step equal to those of the video but the compiler returns me errors like these in the code below.

PokemonAPIList.swift

```
import Foundation

struct PokemonAPIList: Decodable {
    var results: [PokemonListEntry]
}

struct PokemonListEntry: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var url: String
}
```

PokemonNetworkManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class PokemonNetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<PokemonNetworkManager, Never> ()
    
    var pokemonList = PokemonAPIList(results: []) {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            let pokemonList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonAPIList.self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pokemonList = pokemonList
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var networkingManager = PokemonNetworkManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(networkingManager.pokemonList.results.identified(by: \.url)) {pokemon in //HERE THE ERRORS
            Text(pokemon.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

**Following Errors occur:**

> Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type

> Insert '<#Root#>'

> Value of type '[PokemonListEntry]' has no member 'identified'

The only thing I changed is @BindableObject to @ObservableObject because I read online it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
 
struct PokemonAPIList: Decodable {
    var results: [PokemonListEntry]
}

struct PokemonListEntry: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var url: String
}
 
class PokemonNetworkManager: ObservableObject {
  
   @Published var results = [PokemonListEntry]()
     
    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            let pokemonList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonAPIList.self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.results = pokemonList.results
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
  
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkingManager = PokemonNetworkManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(networkingManager.results,id:\.name) {pokemon in
            Text(pokemon.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks. It worked, but can you explain me why the code I wrote copying that video (in which the code works) doesn't work?